# How can we limit GDB to debug only a specific source (for example yacc/lex) for step + next instructions?

Tags: debugging, gdb

When debugging a source file that is full of `#line` directives the debugger "switches" between those files accordingly.

**Issue:** only one file is intended to be debugged

**Example:**
As an example one can use yacc/bison lex/flex which translate a grammar to C source. The result is something like this (the actual content is irrelevant to the question, this is just the first sample that I've looked at):

```c
  case 50:
#line 918 "parse.y" /* yacc.c:1652  */
    {
    struct my_struct    *p;

    p = ppp_define_add (ppp_setvar_list, (yyvsp[-3].s), (yyvsp[-1].s), (yyvsp[0].ui));
    if (p) {
        ppp_last_entry = p;
    }
  }
#line 2330 "parse.c" /* yacc.c:1652  */
    break;

  case 51:
#line 927 "parse.y" /* yacc.c:1652  */
    {
    struct my_struct    *p;
    size_t          size;
```

When debugging code like this GDB shows the original source or generated and compiled source, depending on the actual position which is fine in general. The problem arises if you *only* want to debug one of those files (which in most cases will be the original source).

**Things I've tried so far:**

1. delete the file one doesn't want to skip through.

   `144     parse.c: No such file or directory.`
2. `skip file` when GDB showed the "unwanted" file. This strangely leads GDB (8.2.1) to still go back to the file, just only output that we're in there:

```
157     in parse.c
(gdb) s
159     in parse.c
(gdb) s
160     in parse.c
(gdb) s
161     in parse.c
```

**Questions:**

1. Is there an option in GDB to only skip/next into a specific file (in this case parse.y)?
2. Is there an option to strip the debugging information *for only parse.c* or parse.y from the binary?

Ideally the backtrace `bt` and similar commands will only show parse.y.

Comment: Where did `#line 2330 "parse.c"` come from? `bison` is *not* supposed to generate such lines. Re: debugging only `parse.c` -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45474518/50617

Comment: `bison` and `flex` normally insert those which is reasonable as you compile the generated file (rule of thumb: if you add something like `#line 123 "origin.stuff"` you also should generate `#line 123 "generated.stuff"` for things that are outside of the origin).

Answer (score 0):

GDB does not have a "skip everything except this" option. You can skip files and/or functions (possible using a pattern). Therefore, you best option is to add the names of the files (or use a pattern) to your `.gdbinit` file.

But by using the Python API we can do much more with GDB. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676241/tell-gdb-to-skip-standard-files) has a lot of useful information. Particularly, the last answer seems very similar to what you want.

Comment: Actually ignoring in any way seems to not work, I _assume_ that this is only handled when the frame changes - and in this case the frame is always the same.
The [referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49200729/5027456) does work "somehow" (currently leaving a bunch of unwanted output in gdb, but this possibly can be adjusted). Note: I' don't look for "skip everything but", I just look for "not include this specific file, even on the same frame".